Login/Register working but now showing ProfileView only after restarting the App
I am working on a chat app but for now i have just the Login/Register and ProfileView. If i log in with the correct data i just get a blank screen. After i restart the App(close and reopen) it shows me my ProfileView like i want.
It shows me an Exclamation mark on ContentView but i don't see the error. Please help me
all the Code of my Project with the names:
ConnectifyApp
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct ConnectifyApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewModel = AuthViewModel()
    
    init(){
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
        }
    }
}

InputView
import SwiftUI

struct InputView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    let title: String
    let placeholder: String
    var isSecureField = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading, spacing: 12){
            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(Color(.magenta))
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .font(.footnote)
            
            if isSecureField{
                SecureField(placeholder, text: $text)
                  .font(.system(size: 14))
            }
            else
            {
                TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
                  .font(.system(size: 14))
            }
        }
      .padding(12)
      .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
      .cornerRadius(12)
    }
}

#Preview {
    InputView(text: .constant(""), title: "Email Adress", placeholder:"Email Adress")
}


AuthViewModel
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

@MainActor
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    
    init() {
        self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
        
        Task{
            await fetchUser()
        }
    }
    
    func signIn(withEmail email: String, password: String) async throws{
        do{
            let result = try await Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
            self.userSession = result.user
        } catch {
            print("DEBUG: Failed to log in with error\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func createUser(username: String, withEmail email: String, password: String) async throws{
        do{
            let result = try await Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
            self.userSession = result.user
            let user = User(id: result.user.uid, username: username, email: email)
            let encodedUser = try Firestore.Encoder().encode(user)
            try await Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.id).setData(encodedUser)
            await fetchUser()
        } catch {
            print("DEBUG: Failed to create user with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func signOut(){
        do{
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            self.userSession = nil
            self.currentUser = nil
        } catch {
            print("DEBUG: Failed to sign out with error\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func deleteAccount(){
        print("Deleting Account...")
    }
    
    func fetchUser() async{
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        guard let snapshot = try? await Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).getDocument() else { return }
        self.currentUser = try? snapshot.data(as: User.self)
        
        print("DEBUG: Currsnt user is\(String(describing: self.currentUser))")
    }
}

LoginView
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            VStack{
                //Logo
                Image("Logo3")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 100)
                    .padding(.vertical, 32)
                Spacer()
                
                //Input
                VStack{
                    
                    InputView(text: $email,
                              title: "Email",
                              placeholder: "name@example.com")
                    .autocapitalization(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.none/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    
                    InputView(text: $password,
                              title: "Password",
                              placeholder: "Password",
                              isSecureField: true)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .padding(.top, 10)
                //Button
                Button{
                    Task{
                        try await viewModel.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
                    }
                } label: {
                    HStack{
                        Text("Sign in")
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 15, height: 48)
                }
                .background(Color(.systemBlue))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.top, 5)
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                //Register
                NavigationLink{
                    RegistrationView()
                        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                } label: {
                    HStack(spacing: 5){
                        Text("Don't have an Account?")
                        Text("Sign Up")
                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    }
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    LoginView()
}

RegistrationView
import SwiftUI

struct RegistrationView: View {
    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @State private var confirmPassword = ""
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //Logo
            Image("Logo3")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 100)
                .padding(.vertical, 32)
            Spacer()
            
            //Input
            
            VStack{
                InputView(text: $username,
                          title: "Username",
                          placeholder: "Username")
                .autocapitalization(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.none/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                
                InputView(text: $email,
                          title: "Email",
                          placeholder: "name@example.com")
                .autocapitalization(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.none/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                
                InputView(text: $password,
                          title: "Password",
                          placeholder: "Password",
                          isSecureField: true)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
                
                InputView(text: $confirmPassword,
                          title: "Confirm Password",
                          placeholder: "Password",
                          isSecureField: true)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
            .padding(.top, 10)
            
            //Button
            Button{
                Task{
                    try await viewModel.createUser(username: username,
                                                   withEmail: email,
                                                   password:password)
                }
            } label: {
                HStack{
                    Text("Sign up")
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 15, height: 48)
            }
            .background(Color(.systemBlue))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding(.top, 5)
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
            
            Button{
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                HStack(spacing: 5){
                    Text("Already have an Account?")
                    Text("Sign In")
                        .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                }
                .font(.system(size: 14))
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    RegistrationView()
}


ProfileView

import SwiftUI

struct ProfileView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        if let user = viewModel.currentUser{
            List{
                Section{
                    HStack{
                        Text(user.initials)
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 72, height: 72)
                        
                            .background(Color(.systemGray3))
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4){
                            Text(user.username)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .padding(.top, 4)
                            
                            Text(user.email)
                                .font(.footnote)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                Section("General"){
                    HStack{
                        SettingsRowView(imageName: "gear",
                                        title: "Version",
                                        tintColor: Color(.systemGray))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("1.0.0")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                }
                
                Section("Account"){
                    Button{
                        viewModel.signOut()
                    } label: {
                        SettingsRowView(imageName: "power",
                                        title: "Sign Out",
                                        tintColor: .red)
                    }
                    
                    Button{
                        print("deleting account...")
                    } label: {
                        SettingsRowView(imageName: "trash.fill",
                                        title: "Delete Account",
                                        tintColor: .red)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ProfileView_Previews: PreviewProvider{
    static var previews: some View{
        let viewModel = AuthViewModel()
        return ProfileView()
           .environmentObject(viewModel)
    }
}



ContentView
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Group{
            if viewModel.userSession != nil {
                ProfileView()
            } else {
                LoginView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider{
    static var previews: some View{
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(AuthViewModel())
    }
}


User
import Foundation

struct User: Identifiable, Codable{
    let id: String
    let username: String
    let email: String
    
    var initials: String{
        let formatter = PersonNameComponentsFormatter()
        if let components = formatter.personNameComponents(from: username){
            formatter.style = .abbreviated
            return formatter.string(from: components)
        }
        return ""
    }
}

extension User{
    static var MOCK_USER = User(id: NSUUID().uuidString,
                                username: "Test Hans",
                                email: "hans@gmail.com")
}



You have some placeholder tags in your code. try to remove all /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/ and /*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, either by entering a true value or removing those strings manually. It should remove some of Xcode's warning, but it is probably not the real issue.
